# Microsoft MAC, MAG or GCC differences

Tags: azure, office365, azure-gov

There are several cloud environment provided by Microsoft.
E.g. Microsoft Azure Government Cloud (**MAG**), Microsoft Azure Commercial (**MAC**) or public cloud, Office 365 (public) cloud and several other Government cloud in EU and Asia. For US Gov there is  **Office 365 GCC** cloud.

Is Office 365 GCC meant for US Government only? Or is it available outside US also?

Comment: Found all the answer. MAC - Microsoft Azure Commercial Or Public Cloud, MAG - Microsoft Azure Gov cloud , GCC - Government Community Cloud (used in context with Office365 [or O365] ). GCC is for US Gov only. There are several Azure Gov cloud for different countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the [Office 365 GCC service description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/office-365-platform-service-description/office-365-us-government/gcc)? I think that should help answer the question.